# How to I copy a TAB to clipboard

Tags: php, html, forms, special-characters, clipboard

I have 2 PHP pages.

Page 1:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/plain');
  echo "John Doe"."\t"."123 Main Street";
?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
  echo "name<input type='text'><br><br>";
  echo "address<input type='text'>";
?>
```

I want to copy the data from page 1 to the clipboard and paste it into the two input fields.  Since there is a tab character between them, I thought I'd be able to just do one paste into the first input field and it would tab to field 2 and paste the rest, but the clipboard seems to lose the TAB. Any ideas?

Comment: After some experimenting I discovered that the clipboard can hold a TAB, however, it doesn't seem to work with text inputs.  If I paste into a textarea, you can see the tab.  Any idea how to make it work with text inputs? I want the tab to move you to the next input.  Or if there's another way to divide the text into the two input fields, that would be fine too.

Comment: Tabs aren't really a thing that exists in a web environment... In html, the tab _symbol_ is treated like any other whitespace and collapsed, and the [tab] _key_ in a browser just moves your focus to the next control.

Comment: @CheeseFlavored A string holds text, not keypresses. The tab character found in a string is completely different than the tab key on your keyboard which happens to have this extra functionality (rather than inserting the appropriate character).